# soapUI client certificate cache

Tags: soapui, client-certificates

I have some web service developed and uses client certificate authentication. I have DEV and QA environments, each environment has been configured to use different client certificate, but the code behind them are the same.

I use soapUI 5.2.0 to invoke the services. When I ran the testing against DEV I provided DEV cert (p12 file) to soapUI tool, it works fine. When I try to switch to QA server, I changed soapUI setting to use QA cert but I got authentication failed error.

If I load the QA cert into my local computer's cert store, and I opened the QA URL in my browser it works fine, which means the service and cert are configured properly.

it looks like the soapUI just memorizes the first client certificate ever used.

Anybody knows how can I clean the *cache* from soapUI?